# Opening CC crashes springboard; any way to fix?

Tags: ios, crash, jailbreak, safe-mode, springboard

My phone's jailbroken; there is no denying it.
It is generally pretty reliable, with only a couple of previous springboard crashes caused by the Control Center. But now, every time I open my spring board, it crashes. CrashReporter's main suspect is `libFlipswitchSpringBoard.dylib`, and the other suspect is `libflipswitch.dylib`. I've re-installed both of those, but it just keeps crashing. I've also re-installed FlipControlCenter. Is there any way to fix this?

I can provide the long list of tweaks installed, but I'll need to update it first.

I have an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.3.3 jailbroken with [totaly-not.spyware.lol](https://totally-not.spyware.lol/) (g0blin method I think, but maybe doubleH3lix).

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yTHHs198Jw4hur1yEvWJ0IEl2_j6lgfp) is a google docs link to the crash report for anyone who can understand it.

Comment: Removing FlipControlCenter fixes this problem, but I rely heavily on it. I'm afraid it may be conflicting with CCPlus

Comment: Nope, when CCPlus is removed when FlipControlCenter isn't it still crashes

Comment: Try asking on [r/jailbreak](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/), you might be able to get better help there.